# How can I create hand-drawn style graphics for my website?

Tags: website-design, icon, images

I am developing a web page for web based application, i am new to web design, so forgive if i have asked very basic question.

i want to create icons and embed into my existing png image file. i have attached sample image below and circle the icon which i want.

[image]

so i want to know how to embed the icons into the image, is there any specific tool to create those icons?.

Comment: You should give attribution (i.e., a URL) for that image. I would guess that's a requirement for both this site and the one you got the image from (if that site would allow it at all, though with attribution it's probably covered under fair use).

Comment: Using SVGs may be good for something like this so that they can be scaled and changed as needed in the browser itself

Comment: The best way to create hand drawn graphics is to draw them by hand. The ones in the example look like they were drawn with a mouse or tablet, the stroke is consistent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you already have your banner and are wondering about the little drawings on top, then I can think of two ways of getting them:

1) **Buy them** online, already made. Sites like [iStock](http://www.istockphoto.com) or [GraphicRiver](http://graphicriver.net/) offer vector illustrations with transparent backgrounds, so it's quite easy to open the files and just paste them on your banner. There are also free icons you can use. Take a look at [Vecteezy](http://www.vecteezy.com/), [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/) or [FlatIcon](http://www.flaticon.com/), to name just a few.

2) **Draw them** yourself. You can either use your mouse (Illustrator or Inkscape would be better for this), or, if you are interested in drawing you could get a graphic tablet. The small ones are not that expensive, and in any case if it's your thing it would be nothing but an investment.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks.. i have decided to draw my own using illustrator, which seems to more creative and originality.

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of software out there, some free and some paid.

Just to list a few:

## FREE

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)

[Ultimate Paint](http://www.ultimatepaint.com/)

[InkScape](https://inkscape.org)

[Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/)

## Paid

[Adobe Fireworks](https://creative.adobe.com/en/products/fireworks)

[Adobe Photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html)

[Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html)

[CorelDRAW](http://www.coreldraw.com)

All of which have different learning curves, you can fin more graphics software by doing a quick Google search.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you have two options:

1. You can hand-draw the icons on paper, and scan them into an image-editing program. You can turn the "icon" into a fixed-size PNG with a transparent background, or into a scale-able SVG file. Then, just upload that image into your website, turn it into a link, and position it correctly... using absolute, fixed, float, etc CSS styles.
2. You can embed the hand-drawn icons as part of the background image itself. Then, you'll be working with just a single large image. You can turn different parts of that image into links by creating an [image-map url](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) in something like Dreamweaver. What that means is that you identify a part of your image (via coordinates) to be a link -- an area that you can "shape" into being the same form and location as in your background image.